# Make Knockout computeds subscribe to observables not in initial execution path?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following problem:

```
self.observables.disableDeleteNumberButton = ko.computed(function () {
    return !self.observables.isEditableReceivable() || !self.observables.aRNumber();
});
```

As `self.observables.aRNumber` doesn't get evaluated when the computed is initialised, the computed does not seem to subscribe to changes for this observable.

I could force the evaluation with something like:

```
self.observables.disableDeleteNumberButton = ko.computed(function () {
    var editableReceivable = self.observables.isEditableReceivable();
    var aRNumber = self.observables.aRNumber();
    return !editableReceivable || !aRNumber;
});
```

But that doesn't look very nice...

What would be the proper way of doing this in Knockout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computed is okay, it is doing what it should be doing.
The problem is that this `return !self.observables.isEditableReceivable() || !self.observables.aRNumber();` may lead to short circuit evaluation.

If `!self.observables.isEditableReceivable()` results to true, then the `!self.observables.aRNumber()` doesn't need to be evaluated. Eventhough how much you change the value of `self.observables.aRNumber()`, it still wouldn't reach this line `!self.observables.aRNumber()` if this line `!self.observables.isEditableReceivable()` still results to true.

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gkmm8s7m/).

Clicking "Toggle AR Number" button would never fire the computed except if you clicked "Toggle Editable Receivable" button first.

=====================

EDIT: I don't really know if this type of answer should be in here or should I add it as a comment to the question. But i'll just wait for the mods :D

Comment: You're right.. It doesn't subscribe to the second observable at init but it does once it reaches it in a later stage. So it doesn't pose a problem after all.

Comment: Yeah, but this answer doesn't really answer on how knockout knows beforehand that there will be a short circuit evaluation at the end and then does not perform the statements before the return statement.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with Knockout quite a bit, and had not yet encountered this problem yet (much to my surprise, because it's a fairly straightforward issue).

To answer your question: AFAIK the idea of your workaround is about the only option. I can only think of variations with other syntax, or perhaps ways to factor it out to a utility method.

If you really *need* the short circuiting e.g. for performance you can check [these docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-reference.html) and utilize `ko.computedContext.isInitial()`.

Comment: There was no need for a workaround. As long as the computed short-circuits there is no need for a subscription on other observables. It appears to subscribe to the next observable once it reaches it later.